# node.js - redirect to Google logout, then back to page

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am using Google login with passport and I want to log the user out, but afterwards bring them back to my app. I'm looking do something like the following, but after it goes to the Google logout, my app does not go to the second redirect link. Is there any way to do this?

The passport method for logging out (req.session.logout()), doesn't seem to actually log out the user unless I exit the browser. Going to the Google logout link seems to ensure logging out, which is why I am using the link.

```
// route for logging out
router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('https://accounts.google.com/logout');
    res.redirect('https://myapp.com'); //Doesn't run this
});
```

Comment: HTTP does not support that

Comment: good way to upset your users. Obviously something wrong in your application logout code

Comment: The problem with the passport logout is that it doesn't seem to completely log them out of Google. This means the user session is destroyed in my app, but the user is still logged in to Google. So if a user logs out and then tries to sign in again, it doesn't give them the opportunity to change accounts, since Google assumes they are already logged in and thus doesn't ask them for account info again. So how do apps using Google login, log their users out?